# Drawing a semi-transparent rectangle on a jpeg file with wx.Bitmap

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to load a jpeg->draw a semi-transparent rectangle->save the jpeg file
using wx.Bitmap of the python wx package.
But the rectangle appears fully opaque.

I'm using Windows 7 with 32bpp.
I checked and try the "Docs and Demos\demo\AlphaDrawing.py" wx demo, and it works well.
It draws correctly on wx.Panel a semi-transparent rectangle.

I checked on the internet for a solution for this problem, but none of the solutions worked.

I created a more simple example, to minimize the possibilities of error, and still didn't work.
Load a jpg->draw a semi-transparent rectangle->save as jpg file

```
wimg = wx.Image(r"N:\Images\Wallpapers\Processed\a.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
print wimg.HasAlpha()
wimg.InitAlpha()
print wimg.HasAlpha()
bmp = wimg.ConvertToBitmap()
print bmp.HasAlpha()
dc = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
r, g, b = (34,  34,  34)
dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.Colour(r, g, b, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE)))
dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(r, g, b, 128)))
dc.DrawRectangle(100, 300, 200, 200)
bmp.SaveFile(r"N:\Images\Wallpapers\Processed\b.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG)
```

The print results are: False/True/True
And still the output it's a fully opaque rectangle

I known jpeg doesn't has alpha channels, but I don't want a 32bpp jpeg. 
Just the output to show rectangle blended with the background.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap files have no Alpha channel. You must load a PNG file to use transparency.

"Unlike RGB data, not all images have an alpha channel and before using GetAlpha you should check if this image contains an alpha channel with HasAlpha. Note that currently only images loaded from PNG files with transparency information will have an alpha channel."

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html

Comment: Good point! I read the documentation and it matches what you mention.
But, now I did some tests loading 32bpp .png and .bmp using Windows 7. And actually the results are the opposite.
If I do: 
    print wimg.HasAlpha()
    bmp = wimg.ConvertToBitmap()
    print bmp.HasAlpha()
I get true twice on the .bmp loading, and false on the .png

But this still doesn't solves my problem.
I'm going to update the post, to reflect the real problem: 
Drawing a semi-transparent rectangle on a jpeg file